# What is the practical NDB count() limit on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

We are trying to query App Engine datastore for some general stats using NDB. They don't need to be 100% accurate (i.e., I'm not concerned about eventual consistency); they just need to reflect generally the count of entities.

With NDB, we are issuing simply something like:

```
query = MyModel.query(MyModel.source==source, MyModel.created<=some_time).order(-MyModel.created)
count = query.count(keys_only=True)
```

This is timing out after around 60s. We use entity groups and transactions fairly regularly, but I'm hoping that those would not impact these count queries. We currently have around 4.2M entities of `MyModel`, though the `source` filter would be limiting this down to perhaps 210,000.

Is there an alternate way to count numbers of this magnitude, without a bunch of custom memcache-y logic? Remember, the numbers don't need to be exact, just "generally correct".

Comment: Typo: of course there should have been a `MyModel.query().filter()...` in there...

Comment: You can just edit the post. Also you can specify your filters as kwargs to `query` to achieve the same effect. Why do you need `order` if you are just counting?

Comment: You're right - the order is irrelevant - except I use it to target a custom index that already exists in my index.yaml and don't have to create a new one.

Comment: Very nice. I'm not sure if this has any impact on the `count` query though. It'd be nice to find out; I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the limit, previously 1000, has now been removed. So the practical limit is then how many can be counted before the timeout.

Some similar questions have been asked and normally [Sharded Counters](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) are brought up at this point.

<del>But I think you will probably be better off running your counter either as a task (time out goes to 10 minutes) or on a backend (no timeout at all).</del>

As Guido notes in the comments **queries cannot take longer than 60 seconds.**

EDIT: 1000 limitation was removed some time ago, 1.3.6:
[Release Notes:](http://googleappengine.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/multi-tenancy-support-high-performance_17.html)

> The Datastore no longer enforces a 1000 entity limit on for count and offset. Queries using these will now safely execute until they return or your application reaches the request timeout limit.

Comment: Note that this is already running in a task (10 minutes). The timeout that I'm seeing is a Datastore RPC timeout. Can I extend that past 60s? If so, that's an easy fix in this particular case.

Comment: Not as far as I know. I've seen some alternatives using cursors to count large numbers of entities but that I suspect would fall under the "memcache-y logic" that you want to avoid. Hopefully someone will be along shortly with some insight onto the timeout issue. I'd probably try it (count) on a backend just to see what happened at this point.

Comment: No matter what environment you use, queries cannot take longer than 60 seconds (used to be 30).  After that the internal "handle" representing the query will time out.  So if you really want the Datastore to count something that takes longer, you'll have to use cursors (and that means a keys-only query; AFAIK you can't get a cursor out of a count() operation).